# WCF web service metadata contains computer name

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, iis

My web service is hosted in IIS on my server, when i try to download the metadata of the service it gives me an error: The remote name could not be resolved: win2008x64 (server name). On server, i have 2 bindings, one http, the other one is https..
How can i resolve this issue?

**EDIT:**

```
The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://win2008x64:1668/Service.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
  - The remote name could not be resolved: 'win2008x64'
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://89.x.x.x:166x/Service.svc?wsdl'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://89.x.x.x:166x/Service.svc?wsdl'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: a: can the client ping the server by name? b: what happens when you browse to the endpoint in a browser?

Comment: Yes of course it can ping, and i can access endpoint in browser, but what it shows on this page:
svcutil.exe https://win2008x64:1667/Service.svc?wsdl
win2008x64  is the problem, it should give the ip..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [WcfExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) ([how to use](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUse&referringTitle=Home)) project on codeplex to deal with this kind of issue. This is also useful if your server is behind a proxy of some kind. You need only to define a location attribute and override the url to your service:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Sample.WsdlSampleEndpointBehavior">
      <wsdlExtensions location="http://127.0.0.1/Sample/WsdlSample.svc" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

try generating the wsdl using the ip address of your server. If it is a public server use the external ip (whatsmyip.org), could be just a Dns issue.

Comment: try generating the wsdl using the ip address of your server.
HOW?
On client side i generate the proxy class through ip of course..

Comment: https://win2008x64:1667/Service.svc?xsd=xsd1, i found this in my wsdl, how to change the win2008x64 to the ip?

Comment: I had a similar scenario the other day where this other business exposed a WCF service and it had the servername in the wsdl file. I think using the servername is the wsdl is the default behavior  of WCF (according to this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ec88418b-0177-44e2-bbd0-0daa85e34615/). I used svcutil with the ip addressof the server and it worked fine. Correct me if I am wrong, but is your real problem is not to expose the name of the server ?

Comment: The client and the server are in different networks, so i connect to him through ip, not the name of computer..